# How to run query like @Sql for test in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I created a Repository and writing a Test Case. I want to run *insert.sql* before executing the test method with @Sql (org.springframework.test.context.jdbc) 
but it doesn't run. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue, Spring Data R2DBC doesn't support @SQl annotation yet.

Use the function below:

```java
    private void executeSqlScriptBlocking(final Resource sqlScript) {
        Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
                .flatMap(connection -> ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, sqlScript)
                        .then(Mono.from(connection.close())))
                .block();
    }
```

Then:

```java
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @BeforeEach
    void init(@Value("classpath:init_test_data.sql") Resource sqlScript) {
        executeSqlScriptBlocking(sqlScript);
    }
```

application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  r2dbc:
    pool:
      enabled: true
      initial-size: 8
      max-size: 16
```

When **connection pool** in used in tests, we should close every created connection because it seems to be not released. Example, if we have 16 pool size, we'll be able to execute only 16 tests then get an infinite loop started from 17th.

Tested on:

```sh
Java: 8(jdk-8.0.272.10-hotspot)
Spring Boot: 2.3.9
JUnit 5: 5.6.3
```