# initialize database for testing purpose on Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

In a non-test environment, I can set up the bean to initialize the database with the `schema.sql` like this

```
    @Bean
    ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(@Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));

        return initializer;
    }
```

the problem is, I want to do something like this but for testing purpose. I'm trying to do some kind of integration testing with the database so I want the schema to be inserted to a dummy database too.

I've tried using this annotation but it still won't execute

```
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:schema.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
```

I've created a separate `application-test.properties` on my test resources folder containg this properties values

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.r2dbc.username=postgres

logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc=DEBUG
```

and have added `@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")` annotation too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this to be the easiest way to prepare your database test environment

```java
  private void initializeDatabase() {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(dbUrl);
    R2dbcEntityTemplate template = new R2dbcEntityTemplate(connectionFactory);
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS member (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);";
    template.getDatabaseClient().sql(query).fetch().rowsUpdated().block();
  }
```

and call this method on a `@Before` annotation to be run on the tests

for example, this is what I end up with

```java
  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    initializeDatabase();
    insertData();
  }

  private void initializeDatabase() {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(dbUrl);
    R2dbcEntityTemplate template = new R2dbcEntityTemplate(connectionFactory);
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS member (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);";
    template.getDatabaseClient().sql(query).fetch().rowsUpdated().block();
  }

  private void insertData() {
    Flux<Member> memberFlux = Flux.just(
        Member.builder().name("Andrew").build(),
        Member.builder().name("Bob").build(),
        Member.builder().name("Charlie").build(),
        Member.builder().name("Dave").build()
    );
    memberRepository.deleteAll()
        .thenMany(memberFlux)
        .flatMap(memberRepository::save)
        .doOnNext(member -> log.info("inserted {}", member))
        .blockLast();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @kamalhm, I get this error doing that  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'r2dbcEntityTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate  Could you help me

Comment: Hi @AleGallagher,

Take a look at this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692151/how-to-run-query-like-sql-for-test-in-spring-data-r2dbc/68578464#68578464

Comment: what value to give for `dbUrl` ?

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for an answer for this exactly problem. Created a `TestDBInitializer` bean loading a `test-data.sql` file but it's not working even using `@Profile` annotation. A cleaner, althought not ideal, solution I found is using `@Import({ MyTestDbInitializer.class })` like so:

```
@DataR2dbcTest
@Import({ TestDBInitializerConfig.class })
class R2dbcTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        Flux<MyEntity> fluxResult = this.repository.findAll();
        
        StepVerifier.create(fluxResult)
            // do things...
            .thenConsumeWhile(x -> true)
            .expectComplete()
            .log()
            .verify();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyTestDbInitializer {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryInitializer testProfileInitializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        CompositeDatabasePopulator populator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"), new ClassPathResource("test-data.sql")));
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);

        return initializer;
    }
}
```

Still looking for an answer that doesn't need any manual initialization nor the usage of `@Import` annotation.

Comment: this should have been the correct answer.  all other answers are just reading the sql into a string and execute as sql which technically works, but using `ConnectionFactoryInitializer` is a more appropriate approach.

Comment: I found `R2dbcScriptDatabaseInitializer`, but I'm not able to import it because it requires a bean of type `DatabaseInitializationSettings` which seems not to be initialized even when setting spring.sql.init properties in src/test/resources/application.yml

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to reuse the existing `src/main/resources/schema.sql`, you can get it this way (in Kotlin):

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@DataR2dbcTest
class YourRepositoryTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val yourRepository: YourRepository,
    private val r2dbcEntityTemplate: R2dbcEntityTemplate
) {

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        val schema = StreamUtils.copyToString(
            ClassPathResource("schema.sql").inputStream,
            Charset.defaultCharset()
        )
        r2dbcEntityTemplate.databaseClient.sql(schema).fetch().rowsUpdated().block()
    }
```

Also, using `@DataR2dbcTest` already provides an `R2dbcEntityTemplate` bean, so you can inject it in your tests. No need to instantiate it yourself, especially on each test.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up using flyway like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then adding the appropriate configuration

```
@DynamicPropertySource
private static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry){
    registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url",() -> String.format("r2dbc:pool:postgresql://%s:%d/%s",postgres.getHost(),postgres.getFirstMappedPort(),postgres.getDatabaseName()));
    registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username",postgres::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password",postgres::getPassword);
    registry.add("spring.flyway.url",postgres::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.flyway.user",postgres::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.flyway.password",postgres::getPassword);
}
```

That allowed me to define my scripts inside `src/test/resources/db/migration`

Hope it helps.